# What's the meaning of Jon Skeet's phrase?

Tags: meaning

[This](https://www.quora.com/Who-is-Jon-Skeet-and-how-did-he-become-famous-on-Stack-Overflow) Quora question is about Jon Skeet that was answered by himself. He used this phrase - "whatever you happen to think that's worth" (3 paragraph, end of the 1st sentence). What does that mean? I don't get it, please explain.

Answer (score 3):

Let me  put it into context. Quoting from same article.

> In terms of "fame" - I joined Stack Overflow on September 26th 2008, and reasonably rapidly (around January 2009?) ended up as the "top user" in terms of reputation - **whatever you happen to think that's worth**.

What he is trying to say is, reputation is not as much of worth to him. But for some people reputation on Stack Overflow is a benchmark of how much one knows about programming and stuff.

Some people give too much importance to reputation and spend quite a lot of time to see that graph go up. Whereas some people come in for real discussion and problem solving.